Подсказка при вводе данных в ячейку с проверкой
Сменил версию excel. Раньше при начале ввода данных в ячейку сразу появлялись варианты, соответствующие вводу. Сейчас - нет, нужно полностью ввести корректные данные. В чем причина?

Причина в настройках. Предыдущая версия была настроена, а новая и не собиралась. Пройдитесь по настройкам и найдёте. Там всё по-русски.
